# Ethernet Driver for Lenovo S10-3t

Tags: drivers, ethernet, lenovo-laptop

Lenovo doesn't provide 64bit drivers for my Lenovo S10-3t. I'm having problems searching for an Ethernet driver for it.  I can get WiFi to work, but not a physical connection. Can anyone give me a hand locating a proper driver?

Comment: Try to identify the ethernet chip Make and Model and edit your post to include this information, also state if it is wired or wireless.

Comment: I haven't been able to locate the make and model of the chipset, but I can tell you I'm looking for the wired ethernet driver.